# how to create a json array with data from a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, foreach

i have some json files which look like this:

```
{
    "id": "id_11-08-2021",
    "name": "John",
    "date": "11-08-2021",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "starttime": "08:30",
    "endtime": "10:00",
    "hours": 1.5
}
```

To read all the `json` files in a dir i use this code (process.php):

```
$files = glob('data/*.json'); // all json files in dir data
foreach($files as $file) {
    $objs[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1); // all json objects in array             
}
$result = [];
foreach($objs as $key => $val) {
    $result['data'] = array(                                
                        'id' => $val['id'];
                        'date' => $val['date'];
                        'day' => $val['day'];
                        'starttime' => $val['starttime'];
                        'endime' => $val['endtime'];
                        'hours' => $val['hours']                                    
                        );
}
$result['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$result['status'] = 2;
echo json_encode($result); // send back data
```

My jquery ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {
            name: name          
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.status == 2) { // check status of data
                $('tbody').html(response.data); // handle data from server; output data in tbody
                $('.name').html(response.name); // name from user
            }
        },
});
```

I do not receive the data from the foreach loop. What is going wrong?

Comment: First of all, you are overwriting `$result['data']` in each loop iteration, that should be `$result['data'] = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're overwriting your result in the loop constantly. You need to create a new array element within `data` in the loop.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($objs as $key => $val) {
    $result['data'][] = array(                                
        'id' => $val['id'];
        'date' => $val['date'];
        'day' => $val['day'];
        'starttime' => $val['starttime'];
        'endime' => $val['endtime'];
        'hours' => $val['hours']                                    
    );
}
$result['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$result['status'] = 2;
```

Secondly, since you're not changing anything in your loop, you could just use your `$objs` array and remove the loop. The loop doesn't do anything in your example.

```
$result['data'] = $objs;
```

Comment: Did you mean `$result['data'][] = $objs;` for the last example?

Comment: @ADyson No, because `objs` is already an array. $result['data'] should be the same after the loop as if you are doing `$result['data'] = $objs`. `$result['data'][] = $objs` would result in an array like data -> result -> 0 -> *array of jsons*

Comment: If you're saying it should be `$result['data'][] = array(` in the first example, then it should be `$result['data'][]`in the second example. Otherwise it's not equivalent, and you'll end up overwriting `$result['data']` again every time the `foreach` loop runs - which was the original problem.

Comment: @ADyson No, because the first one is a loop that fills the `$result['data']` array with entries. `$result['data'][]` creates a new array entry within the `data` key. But since `$objs` already *is* an array there is not necessity to create a new array entry within result. Because the line `$result['data'] = $objs;` would replace the loop. You are correct if you'd do the loop *and* the line `$result['data'] = $objs;`, but then you would duplicate the data. The line `$result['data'] = $objs;` would replace the loop.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean, sorry

Comment: Strange: I got a 500 error in process.php and the initiator is jquery.min.js. I use the 2.2.4

Comment: @john A 500 error is a server-side error, so it cannot becaused by jQuery directly. Maybe you mean the request which resulted in a 500 was triggered by a jQuery AJAX request, or something? Either way, you need to look in the server's PHP error log to find the underlying error - a 500 code on its own doesn't tell us much.